# Problem regarding the size of the internal memory of AVD platform 2.2 API- lvl 8

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i searched the web to find some guides how to increase the capacity of the internal memory of my virtual device, no luck so far, since i think their talking about the memory of their real phone, not the virtual device.

my problem is after adding some few files on my app, once i run the project as android project, it is having errors like:

*[2011-07-18 12:04:28 - testproject] Failed to install testproject.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2011-07-18 12:04:28 - testproject] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2011-07-18 12:04:28 - testproject] Launch canceled!*

and i can't test if my codes are running correctly since it won't install the app..

i know you can immediately program the app to install itself on the SD card instead of it using the internal memory of the phone, but i just want to end this problem of mine, can i really increase the size of the internal memory? or the size of the internal memory is already fixed? depending on the  android platform, i use android 2.2..

i also tinkered through the hardware of the avd adding and increasing the value of the hardwares, no luck, so if someone could just give me advice or assist me on this problem of mine i would be grateful, since i can't continue my study of the android technology because of this minor setback, thanks and godspeed.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820087/how-to-increase-internal-memory-for-android-4-0-emulator-images) for more specific answer on how to start emulator from command prompt with `-partition-size`parameter

Answer (score 0):

Start the emulator from command line with -partition-size parameter.

Comment: I'm really new with this, so forgive me for my ignorance but could you be more specific, how do i start the emulator and where do i find this command line? thanks