# How to increase internal memory for Android 4.0 Emulator images?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Free internal memory is sparse on Android 4.0, because the system occupies quite some space. This limits the number of apps one can install.

So, how can we increase the internal memory?

In the dialog for creating new AVDs, I didn't see an option for it. What did I miss? I tried some of the partition size options, but it won't affect the internal memory or the emulator hangs during boot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

greenrobot

i couldn't find that option in the UI either.
but you can start the emulator from the command line and specify the size with a parameter.
e.g.:

```
emulator-arm.exe -partition-size 123 -avd myandroid4
```

for me the path to the emulator exe is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\"
replace "123" with your desired partition size and "myandroid4" with the name of your AVD

after starting my avd the free space for apps showed the desired value.
but i didn't try to write data into it.

btw you can also create a shortcut to the emulator.exe so you dont need to start the SDK Manager every time you want to start an avd.

please tell me if that worked for you.
regards
erik

Comment: please don't forget to mark this post as an answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Do we need to run this command once or everytime when emulator starts?

Comment: If you have snapshots enabled, you can start it once from the command line. I used this line to avoid the old snapshot being loaded (does not work with existing snapshots):
emulator -partition-size 128 -no-snapshot-load -avd My4.0